# Creating a self-validating password

Tags: validation, passwords

I'm looking to create a password that will be able to validate itself. My code will both create the password on one platform and validate it on another. For security, we do not want include any key values for encryption/decryption.

My thought is to randomly generate 4 digits (call them R1 - R4), apply a series of calculations to expand this to a very large number, take 4 four digits from various positions in the calculated value (call them C1 - C4) and intersperse both sets of digits in the password (e.g. C3,C1,R4,C2,R1,R3,C4,R2).

To validate, reverse the above.

Programmatically, this is straightforward but from a security perspective is this a sound approach?

Thanks for any feedback,
Mike

Comment: Is it something like the Luhn algorithm? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luhn_algorithm#Strengths_and_weaknesses

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't aware of this. It's basically the same idea although it seems to me that the chances of verifying a false value is 1 in 10 as there is only a single check digit. Using four check digits would increase the chance of verifying a false input to 1 in 9999. I will take a look at the other two methods mentioned: the Verhoeff algorithm and the Damm algorithm. Thanks again - you given a lot more to think about.